# Use apache daffodil to parse NITF to XML

Tags: cmd, dfdl

I am trying to use cmd to parse a NITF file to an XML using apache daffodil.

In cmd, I run `.\daffodil.bat parse --schema nitf.dfdl.xsd 2301573_3.ntf`

The `nitf.dfdl.xsd`, `nitf_common_types.dfdl.xsd`, `nitf_extension_types.dfdl.xsd` and the `NITF` are contained in the same folder as the `daffodil.bat` file. The `NITF` schemas can be found [here](https://github.com/DFDLSchemas/NITF/tree/master/src/main/resources/com/tresys/nitf/xsd)

I get the error:

```
[error] Schema Definition Error: Error loading schema due to org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; 
DaffodilXMLLoader: Unable to resolve 
schemaLocation='com/tresys/nitf/xsd/nitf_common_types.dfdl.xsd'.
Schema context: file:/C:/Users/rinat/OneDrive/Desktop/WORK%20STUFF/apache-daffodil-3.4.0- 
bin/apache-daffodil-3.4.0-bin/bin/nitf.dfdl.xsd Location in 
file:/C:/Users/rinat/OneDrive/Desktop/WORK STUFF/apache-daffodil-3.4.0-bin/apache-daffodil- 
3.4.0-bin/bin/nitf.dfdl.xsd
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nitf schema imports files using the full path, so it expects the imported files to be in a `com/tresys/nitf/xsd/...` directory on the classpath. If you are copying the files out of those expected paths, then you'll need to modify the `xs:import` statements to also not use those paths. For example, these lines in `nitf.dfdl.xsd`:

```xml
  <xs:import namespace="urn:nitfCommonTypes" schemaLocation="com/tresys/nitf/xsd/nitf_common_types.dfdl.xsd" />
  <xs:import namespace="urn:nitfExtensionTypes" schemaLocation="com/tresys/nitf/xsd/nitf_extension_types.dfdl.xsd" />
```

Need to changed to the `schemaLocation` attribute to this:

```xml
  <xs:import namespace="urn:nitfCommonTypes" schemaLocation="nitf_common_types.dfdl.xsd" />
  <xs:import namespace="urn:nitfExtensionTypes" schemaLocation="nitf_extension_types.dfdl.xsd" />
```

The other DFDL schema files may need a similar change.